(Android)Images and videos are not showing in the FILE EXPLORER on Laptop,but are visible in Phone's Gallery
So,my issue's a bit odd in my opinion, because some of my Pictures and Videos are not showing up in my Default File Manager, but all the Photo and Video Files are showing up in the Gallery.
So, I tried to connect my Phone to my Laptop via USB cable, but still some of my photos and videos (with the same amount) are not showing up in my PC File Explorer.
The picture and video Files that do not appear, are years older than the current phone I own.(I bought this Phone after 2020 but the photos and videos are from before 2020)
If possible, a clear-cut explanation in simple English would be helpful.

The Gallery app is probably getting data from cloud services, namely Google Drive.

Its probably because you have deleted those files from your device. But the Gallery app has backed them up in the cloud.
One solution is to find it in the Gallery and do something with that works for you, such has email or copy.
